# Game Text Inputfield and Button not responding

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a word guessing game. My input field is supposed to accept a string and go to the next page if right or return back to the menu page if not right. Currently, my scene is going to the next scene for both the right and wrong answer.

```
public class anser : MonoBehaviour {

    private string secretWord = "eje";
    private string guessWord;

    public void GetInput(string guessWord) {
        //Invoke ("CompareGuesses", 1f);

        if (secretWord == guessWord) {

            SceneManager.LoadScene ("Front Page");

        } else if (secretWord != guessWord) {

            SceneManager.LoadScene ("Question2");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should remove if. It should be else { }.

Comment: While true @Tomato32 with the current code that's not a functional change. OP I don't see the issue in the code posted; you may just need to step through so you can provide more info.

Comment: I don't grab what step through is. I change inverse the script to load scene  when it only recognizes the else statement. The script is to let my page load scene Question 2 if input field is "Eje" and go back to front page if otherwise. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the `guessWord` field is for, all you need is the `guessWord` parameter for your `GetInput()` method.

Also, you need to make sure the scene names are correct (check for capitals and spaces), and make sure that some other script is actually calling the `GetInput()` method (you didn't post the code for anything that calls this method).

Here is a cleaned up version of your code that should do what you want:

```
// The class name "anser" was misspelled. Also you typically use PascalCase for class names.
public class Answer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string secretWord = "eje";

    public void GetInput(string guessWord) 
    {
        if (secretWord == guessWord.ToLower()) 
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Question2");
            return; // eliminates the need for an else clause
        } 

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Front Page");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Per Scriven's suggestions in the comments, I changed the `LoadScene()` arguments to reflect the OP's desired behavior. Also added a little bit of input validation for the `guessWord` parameter.

Comment: This answer looks good, just want to point out OP... It looks like getting the word right sends them to the front page. Also dealing with user input a little might be a good idea. At very least add .ToLower() to the user input so when the user type Eje, eJe, ejE, EJE, EJe, eJE, and EjE doesn't show as wrong.

Comment: @Scriven Excellent points; I will update my answer to include them.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Scriven I  tried Editting the code to yours , I  am still getting the same output. My scene is to load question 2 if input field is "Eje" or go back yo front page if not the secretWord.

Comment: @Bumsque my guess is either the problem isn't here, or no matter what guessWord = eje

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, my guess would be that it is a scene name or nothing calling the `GetInput()` method. Did you add `Debug.Log()` calls in the `GetInput()` method to make sure it's being called and check what path the code is taking? Have you tried adding a breakpoint to the code and stepping through line-by-line?

Comment: @Lews Theron, I am sorry I have to disturb you guys.  Just need to fix this up. I added Debug.Log , it still reading the else statement.

Comment: and what does secretWord and guessWord evaluate to during debug?